# Pass multiple php variables to index page

Tags: php, variables

Update
is there anyway i can use the following code to replace $anagram within the $description using the following code because it will strip what-is-an-anagram-of-listen.php and the output would be listen?

```
$anagram = str_replace('what-is-an-anagram-of-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
```

I have a php script which will list all the files of a certain folder.
It takes the page title and strips it of dashes and uses it as title then it takes the description of the page and echos it.

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('../anagram/')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    preg_match("/name=\"description\" content=\"(.*?)\"/i", file_get_contents("../anagram/".$file), $matches);
    $description = $matches[1];   
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'index.php' && $file != 'error_log') {
            $fileTab[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach($fileTab as $file) {
        $title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
    $content = file_get_contents("../anagram/".$file);
    if (!$content) {

        echo "error reading file $file<br>";
    }
    else {
        preg_match("/description = \"(.*?)\"/i", $content,$matches);
        $description = $matches[1];
    }
        $buy .= '<div class="indexpage"><h6><a href="../anagram/'.$file.'">'.$title.'</a></h6><p>'.$description.'</p><p><a class="button-blue-short" href="../anagram/'.$file.'">Read More &raquo;</a></p></div>';
    }
}
?>

<?=$buy?>
```

The following code is an example of one of the pages in the folder ../anagram/ the index page reads the description and uses it to create the index page.

```
<?php 
$anagram = "listen"; 
$pagetitle = "What is an Anagram of $anagram"; 
$keywords = "Anagram of $anagram"; 
$description = "What is an Anagram of $anagram, an anagram is creating a word or phrase by moving around the letters of a different word or phrase, using all the original letters of $anagram what other words can be made from the word $anagram."; 
include("../include/head.php"); 
?>
```

My problem is on my index page I can’t get the php code to read $anagram from the $desription it just echos it as $anagram but it should say listen.

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents("../anagram/".$file);` - you are only reading the file content into a string here, PHP code inside of it does not get executed that way.

Comment: Have you tried with `$description = "What is an Anagram of ".$anagram.", an anagram is creating a word or phrase by moving around the letters of a different word or phrase, using all the original letters of ".$anagram." what other words can be made from the word $anagram.";`

Comment: if you want to re-use the **code** including variable names from that script you need to use include() or require() (just like you do later with head.php). as misorude says, file_get_contents just loads the content of the file as a string, it does not treat it as executable code.

Comment: @Ishpreet thanks I’ve tried that but it just echoes, what is an anagram of because of the $description = "What is an Anagram of "

Comment: I don't know for sure what your overall goal is here, but you seem to be attempting a convoluted way to implement a (semi-) dynamic content management system. It might be better to use a proper CMS for this, or at least create a database-driven way to load your data, rather than (what appears to be) a whole folder full of near-identical PHP scripts.

Comment: @ADyson that’s exactly what Im doing, I had too many problems using WP so I decided to build my own dynamic site but I wouldn’t know where to start with a database but I need to learn.

Comment: MySQL is not complicated to use. Tutorials are available, including how to work with it in combination with PHP. Or there's SQLite, and others. For this purpose you'd probably only need one table containing all the possible anagram values, and a URL to go with it. Then you could just get all the rows, loop through them and echo a the name and hyperlink for each one. P.S. Wordpress is not primarily a CMS, so it's not the ideal tool for this sort of thing anyway. I'm not entirely surprised you struggled to make it work. It's a PITA in general too (just IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Depending on your setup and PHP version, putting a variable in double quotes should produce the correct output, but you have several other options available:

```
<?php 
  $anagram = "listen";
  $test1 = "some text ${anagram} more text\n";
  $test2 = "some text {$anagram} more text\n";
  $test3 = "some text ".$anagram." more text\n";
  echo $test1;
  echo $test2;
  echo $test3;
?>
```

Should all work correctly.